# PDF ingesting through KIBANA

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to Elasticsearch and there are some requirements where I need to ingest and index pdf using Kibana. I have figured out that we have to create a pipeline for the above purpose but do not know which processor to use and how should I configure those. I discovered that the node of my Elasticsearch has ingest-attachment plugin installed. The version which I am using is Elasticsearch 7.14,so any help on it is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be useful for you, the ingest atachment processor plugin uses base64 for a pdf to extract and ingest data. You would be require to get base64 abd ingest it into a pipeline. For example:

```
encoded_data = base64.b64encode(data).decode('utf-8') # data is the file that you are parsing

body = {    
        'query': { 
            'bool': {
                "filter": [
                    {"ids": { 'values': [contentDocumentId]}},
                    {"term": {"contentVersionId": contentVersionId}}
                ]
            }
        },
        'script': {
            'source': 'ctx._source["file_data"] = params._file_data',
            'params': {'_file_data': encoded_data}
        }
    }
    response = client.update_by_query(conflicts='proceed', index=_index, pipeline='attachment', body=json.dumps(body))
```

I am using **update by query** for my used case you can check if you want to use update or update by query

Comment: First of all which processor should I use to create a pipeline for pdf ingesting? There are many processors available such as append, enrich. dissect etc

Comment: There is ingest attachment processor plugin which is specifically used for this used case.  The code snippet mentioned above is the example of same plugin.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/ingest-attachment.html